# Lost free space in external hard drive after a crash when copying a file

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, ntfs, file-transfer, disk-space

I'm using Linux. I was copying a huge file into my external hard drive (NTFS) when my computer crashed. After booting up again, I realized the free space on my external hard drive has dramatically decreased. I calculated the size of the folders on my external hard drive, but the used space was much greater than the size of everything that I could see in File Manager.

In these situation, I usually would make a backup everything and format my external storage, but that's not an option here.

How can I delete the corrupted file on my external hard drive?

Comment: run chkdsk on the ntfs partition, may have to be done in Windows. chkdsk will correct errors in the bitmap and fix any free space issues in the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran `chkdsk` in a Windows machine. It solved my problem.
`ntfsfix` or `fsck` did not help at all.

Comment: Good approach. [Linux is not well equipped to fix corrupted NTFS](https://superuser.com/a/1144611/432690).