# Why do ntfs entries in fstab have <pass> (fs_passno) 0?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, fstab, fsck

I notice in my `/etc/fstab` that my root partition has 1 in the `<pass>` column, and my home partition has 2 in the `<pass>` column.

This is expected. From man pages:

> The sixth field, (fs_passno), is used by the fsck(8) program to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at reboot time. **The root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1, and other filesystems should have a fs_passno of 2.** Filesystems within a drive will be checked sequentially, but filesystems on different drives will be checked at the same time to utilize parallelism available in the hardware.

My ntfs partitions have `<pass>` 0. Manpages again:

> If the sixth field is not present or zero, a value of zero is returned and fsck will assume that the filesystem does not need to be checked.

Why are ntfs partitions not checked?

Comment: Possibly because [there is no fully-fledged `fsck.ntfs`](https://superuser.com/a/1144611/432690).

Comment: Also possibly because Linux doesn't know how to do that well.