# Unable to delete corrputed files on external hard drive: "File or directory not found"

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, ntfs

I copied (cut & paste) some files from my netbook onto my external hard drive. While copying, the complete OS froze and did not react for a considerable amount of time, so I decided to restart. After restart, I have found that not all files were copied properly.

Now, there are corrputed files on the hard disk that cannot be removed with neither `rm` nor any file manager. The error message is: "*File or directory not found*". Just re-copying the remaining files will also result in the same error.

- Operating system: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS
- External hard disk file system: NTFS

How is it possible to remove those files?

*EDIT*: I only have Linux tools available (i.e., no `chkdsk`). I have tried `ntfsfix -bd /dev/sdc1` as superuser, but that did not resolve my issue. Now, I'm running `testdisk`, which takes a considerable amount of time, so I will not know the results before tomorrow.

Comment: Run a "chkdsk /f" or /r on that drive.

Comment: If you only have Linux you may want to start again -ASSUMING EVERYTHING ON THE EXTERNAL DRIVE IS BACKED UP - repartition it to FAT and reformat. You don't want to deal with NTFS under Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact your OS froze during the write may indicate some hardware is faulty. Telling if the disk is healthy should be your first concern.

The disk is external, it's possible the case is the culprit. It's reasonable to connect the disk directly. You didn't tell us the details but it's probably a SATA disk and you connect the case via USB. If you'd like to connect the disk directly via SATA, be aware of this possible issue: [Why is my USB drive showing corrupted data when plugged as an internal SATA drive?](https://superuser.com/q/985305/432690)

To diagnose the disk:

1. Check S.M.A.R.T. status (`smartctl -a /dev/sdX`) and interpret it.
2. Run S.M.A.R.T. tests (`smartctl -t short /dev/sdX`, `… -t long …`); check status again to see the results.
3. Optionally use `badblocks`.
4. Or use (Windows) `chkdsk /r`. I guess you will need `chkdsk` anyway, so you may as well start with it.

Depending on how the disk behaves and what the results are, at some point you may want to backup your files from it. When in doubt, do it as early as you can.

- The disk is still mountable so you can probably save almost all files with plain `cp`, `rsync` or another tool that works on file level.
- Or you can read the whole disk (or at least the partition with the filesystem) with `ddrescue`.

If the disk is healthy then you may repair the filesystem on the disk. Unfortunately as far as I know [there is no tool to fix corrupted NTFS under Linux](https://superuser.com/a/1144611/432690). You will most likely need `chkdsk` from Windows.

If the disk is not healthy then you may still try to fix the filesystem there (with `chkdsk`). Depending on how severe the situation is you may or may not succeed and you may or may not want to use the disk any longer.

If for whatever reason you can't or don't want to use the disk any longer and the best that's left is the image from `ddrescue` then you should fix the filesystem within the image; again, with `chkdsk`. In Windows it may be possible to [work with an image file](https://superuser.com/q/615683/432690); or write the image to another physical device (if not already written to a device by `ddrescue` in the first place) so `chkdsk` works without additional tricks.

I think there's little chance you can fix your NTFS filesystem in Linux (i.e. without `chkdsk`). A workaround is to copy all the files elsewhere and to rebuild the filesystem from scratch on the same device (if the device is healthy).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am testing the HDD now, see what happens. Actually, I suspect that the OS did not froze because of the hard disk, but just because the OS is broken since an distribution upgrade I made months ago. Since then, it randomly forgets the WiFi card or just freezes and this was my attempt to backup some remaining data to install a new OS. -- Apparently, there is little hope to do this without Windows. Consequently, I will later make a Windows installation medium and boot from it in order to access `chkdsk`.

Comment: Thanks. `chkdsk /f` did it just fine. According to `smartctl`, the device has no errors. The reason for the crash was probably the faulty OS.