# How to remove strange file in NTFS external hard drive: /bin/rm: cannot remove 'file': input/output error

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I have a problem in my external hard drive 5tb samsung. When I try to delete some files (just some files), I receive an error:

`/bin/rm: cannot remove 'file': input/output error`

Everything began when I used FreeFileSync to sync a folder from my computer to the ext hd. The files with problem are all of the files in .Trash-1000 and sync.ffs_lock.

Some files appear in the `ls` output with an * in the end, why that?

An example of `ls` output (I cannot delete none of these files/folders):

```
d?????????    ? ?       ?               ?            ?  Colony/
-rwxrwxrwx    1 camargo camargo    282224 ago  4  2017  Cover.jpg*
```

Whe I do `file` in files/folders with ?, I got an error:

```
file Colony
Colony: cannot open `Colony' (Input/output error)
```

But when I do `file` in the file with an * it seems ok, and when I try to remove with rm, it returns $?=0, but the file are not removed.

```
file Cover.jpg 
Cover.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=12, height=1651, bps=0, PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, orientation=upper-left, width=1213], baseline, precision 8, 441x600, frames 3
```

**What I tried**

1) `ntfsfix /dev/sdc1`

Says that it is ok with the drive.

2) `rm -rf file` or `sudo rm -rf file` or `chown $USER:$USER file && rm -f file`

Same error message

3) Oppened in gnome-disks and scan filesystem (there are no errors) and correct filesystem

Same behavior after.

Comment: See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1144611/432690). I'm not voting to close as duplicate because your issue is somewhat different and I'm not sure `chkdsk /f` in Windows is the right first step. Nevertheless `ntfsfix` is limited and these question marks and `input/output error` probably indicate filesystem corruption and maybe a hardware problem. Have you ruled out the latter? What does SMART say about the drive? Anything interesting in `dmesg` when the error occurs?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and place the relevant information there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess I can't run SMART in an external hard drive over USB (can I?), in gnome-disks the SMART option for this drive is unavailable. `dmesg` shows almost nothing when I tried to remove that files, but when I disconnect the drive the only error I got are this one:
```
[147487.632078] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```
Should I try chkdsk? It is a very weird problem, difficult to guess if is a hardware or filesystem problem.

Comment: [Another similar problem](https://superuser.com/q/1390325/432690), another answer from me. You can try to use `smartctl` with a hard drive connected via USB. Most enclosures support this, some old ones don't.

Comment: Tried:
`sudo smartctl -a -d scsi /dev/sdc` and got `SMART Health Status: OK`, smart support is available but disabled. When I tried to run the short or long test I got `[unsupported field in scsi command]`. The drive is ok then?

Comment: Cannot tell. Do you really need `-d scsi`?

Comment: Yes, I tried withoud -d scsi and it returned `/dev/sdc: Unknown USB bridge [0x0bc2:0xab28 (0x100)]`

Comment: Consider `badblocks` (Linux) or `chkdsk /r` (Windows) to detect hardware problems. Sole `chkdsk /f` may be enough if the hardware is healthy. At the moment I cannot help you further.

Comment: I run the `chkdsk D: /f` and it made a lot of corrections althoug the strange files are still there and cannot be removed, same behavior as before. In output said that were no erros in disk too. Tried `badblocks /dev/sdc` but got `...invalid end block (4883770583): must be 32-bit value`.

Comment: I tried to remove the files in Windows and I could remove most part of them, but not all (I couldn't remove all, but some of them were moved from .Trash-100 to RECICLED.BIN. The another weird thing is that it removed 33.2 TB of files... The chkdsk also removed some sync.ffs_lock weird files that couldn't be remove.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95542/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-octavius).